# Properties of $g$ satisfying $f(x,x)[\nabla_{x}^{2}g(x,y)]_{x=y}+2[\nabla_{x}f(x,y)]_{x=y}\cdot[\nabla_{x}g(x,y)]_{x=y}=0$ for all $f$

Tags: functional-equations, mathematical-physics

Suppose that $g:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that:

$$f\left(x,x\right)\left[\nabla_{x}^{2}g\left(x,y\right)\right]_{x=y}+2\left[\nabla_{x}f\left(x,y\right)\right]_{x=y}\cdot\left[\nabla_{x}g\left(x,y\right)\right]_{x=y}=0$$

holds for all $f:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Here $x$ and $y$ denote points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

The properties that interest me are:

1. Does it follow that $g$ satisfies $\left[\nabla_{x}^{2}g\left(x,y\right)\right]_{x=y}=0$ ?
2. Does it follow that $g$ satisfies $\left[\nabla_{x}g\left(x,y\right)\right]_{x=y}=0$ ?

Note: I am only considering smooth functions $f$ and $g$ here.

Comment: Please, feel free to retitle and/or retag this question if you come up with something more appropriate.

Comment: $\nabla_x$ means $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+...+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$?

Comment: @AnilBaseski Yes. And $\nabla_x^2 = \nabla_x \cdot \nabla_x$ is the Laplacian with respect to $x_1,...,x_n$.

Comment: Why do you think they must be zero? They don't include differantials $d\ x_i$?

Comment: @AnilBaseski I don't understand your question.

Comment: I wanted to say that 1 and 2 can be solution sets but they are not supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is holding for every $f$, let's take $f = 1$. It answers the first question.

Then take $f(x,y) = x$, it answers the second question.

Comment: So that answers the first question: $\left[\nabla_{x}^{2}g\left(x,y\right)\right]_{x=y}=0$. As for the second question, you **cannot** take $f(x,y)=x$, because $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f(x,y)$ is supposed to be a scalar.

Comment: To fix it, just take $f(x,y)=a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n$. Then vary $(a_1,...,a_n)$, to conclude that $\nabla_x g(x,y)=0$.

Comment: @Tomás +1 Thanks.